# Is vaginoplasty after childbirth to improve my husband's sexual pleasure permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, women, sex, medical

After having a child (where the delivery was normal) my husband is having a hard time fulfilling his sexual desire with me; not because of outward appearance, but during sex when he is inside me.  There are surgeries available to help fix the situation:

> Vaginoplasty is a procedure that aims to "tighten up" a vagina that's become slack or loose from vaginal childbirth or aging.  -- [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/women/guide/vaginoplasty-and-labiaplasty-procedures)

However, I'm not sure if these types of surgeries are halal (due to necessity) or haram.

I have also noticed the change with myself and feel very depressed and embarrassed by this thing.  Please, I'm seeking the most correct knowledge on this situation.

Comment: Have you already tried to train the muscles in/around your pelvic floor? There are exercises (e.g. Kegel exercises) that are commonly used to treat/prevent incontinence also in the context of childbirth. They have or at least can have positive side effects that should help with your problem since they give your more control over your muscles in that general area. I'm just wondering if there is a specific reason you consider surgery when there are non-operative alternatives.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=127053).

Comment: I myself would agree with The Raven Queen. Only perform natural remedies because surgical procedures can bring a lot of side- effects, even severe side effects along the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try first what Raven Queen suggested you to do (e.g. Kegel exercises).

**Kegel exercises (including Leg up exercises):**

What these exercises do is strengthen the pelvic floor muscles, which can help tighten the vagina. The great news is that these exercises are easy to perform, you can do them anywhere, and they don’t require any special equipment.

Here’s how it works:

- First, you have to find the right muscles. To do this, try stopping urination midstream. These are the exact muscles that you need to work. Once you get a feel for how to activate these muscles, you can do these exercises in any position.
- Start by tightening your muscles, and holding the contraction for five seconds.
- Now, relax these muscles for five seconds. Do this four to five times in a row.
- Eventually, you want to work your way up to relaxing and contracting for 10 seconds each. Repeat this three times per day, and remember to breathe freely during each session (don’t hold your breath).

**Gels:**

According to many doctors and surgeons gels based on ingredients like Aloe vera or Manjakani Extract (this potent herb is rich in vitamins C and A, carbohydrates, proteins and minerals) are a waste of time and money. They won't get you the same results of women who undergo surgery.

**Vaginoplasty/Hymenoplasty/...:**

It is permissible to undergo such a procedure with the intention to please the husband only if you have tried everything the natural ways first to avoid this.

Sources:

http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=127053

http://www.vaginaltighteningwand.com/how-to-tighten-your-vagina-naturally/

https://www.realself.com/question/california-md-virgin

https://islamqa.info/en/1006

Comment: Permissible according to whom? Note that the islamqa website itself says "The questioner shouldn’t think that such a fatwa can legalize what he has asked about." It's very dangerous to say outright that something is "permissible" as if you're the voice of truth, without rigorous justification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any beauty/pleasing treatment permissible for your husband.
Irrespective of if any other natural or simpler way available/possible or not but with one condition the surgery should be performed by female and showing your body to non Mahram male is Haram.

**In this regard refer to following Hadith**
There are reports in the Sunnah which indicate that circumcision for women is prescribed in Islam. In Madeenah there was a woman who circumcised women and the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said to her: “Do not go to the extreme in cutting; that is better for the woman and more liked by the husband.”  Narrated by Abu Dawood (5271), classed as saheeh by Shaykh al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.